# Power BI Get Parent Name using dax

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

Hi I am new to Power BI.
I want to get parent name which based on parent code as table mention here.
I have manage to do that using duplicate table in model and perform join. But I need to do that using dax expression as new column. Appreciate your help here.

[image]

as table above I want to get parent name based on parent code.
eg.100 = A

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this expression in a **calculated column**

```
Parent Name = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    'Table'[Name],'Table'[Code],
    'Table'[ParentCode])
```

[image]